Spring Boot doesn't fail if 2 same beans are defined
Recently, I worked with standard tasks using Spring Boot and was faced with unexpected behavior.
I have annotation configurations with @Bean annotations and I need to register one of two beans if a specific property is present. Also, I need to inject a created bean into other beans under a specified bean name. I tried to do it as follows:
@Bean("bean-1")
//Specific conditional on property
fun s1() = "1"

@Bean("bean-1")
//Specific conditional on property
fun s2() = "2"

@Bean
fun result(
    @Qualifier("bean-1") b: String
): Any? {
    return null
}

But I got an unexpected result for me. That works. Spring does not fail, however I defined 2 beans with the same type and even with the same name. Spring ignored the conflict. I went further and added some conditionals as follows:
@Bean("bean-1")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = ["bean-1"])
fun s1() = "1"

@Bean("bean-1")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["some_property"], matchIfMissing = true)
fun s2() = "2"

@Bean
fun result(
    @Qualifier("bean-1") b: String
): Any? {
    return null
}

That also works, but Spring ignores creating a bean in method s2!
Help please is it an expected behavior of Spring Boot?
I use Spring Boot 3.3.5.

Don't add code as images, but as text with proper code tags!

@M.Deinum Sry I tried to show how debug works

In addition to preventing copying the text, images also don't work with screen readers and other assistive technologies, can't be searched or indexed, can be hard to read on devices with small screens, increase the download size, fix a particular resolution and rendering of text which might be hard to read on other systems, and are likely to become unavailable in the future when this question might still be useful.  Plus they impose your choice of light-on-dark or dark-on-light, which is also something some people find hard to read!

I am guessing this behavior is because you have the second bean annotated with @ConditionalProperty, which checks if the bean with the specific name is registered, if it is not its created, if it is it does nothing, that is why spring is not failing. You can also check if you are on intelij your active beans under dubug and actuator to see your live bean. Only one should be active.
Beans
